# .fadeIn() / fadeOut() on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a problem with smooth fadeIn and fadeOut in mousemove... I am doing some calculations about what is under top element, and based on those calculations I would like to `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` tooltip. The problem is that when moving a mouse, events are being shoot like every few milliseconds.

The sitiuation looks like this:

I move the mouse, tooltip is hidden. Suddenly mouse pointer is on top of element that should trigger fadeIn(), but this element is not the triggerer, because it is behind of some other element. So I need to shoot `fadeIn()` from mousemove. But, when I shoot it, every few milliseconds, it doesn't work, or works million times. But generally, it does not... animation simply stucks as long as I move mouse, because fadeIn() is being called all over again. I am really tired of this, tried to fix it for like 5 hours and nothing.

I've tried:

1. `.stop()` before `fadeIn()` / `fadeOut()` in different configurations... but the only visible effect I got was that it looked like `show()`, because `stop(true,true)` simply deletes the queue and leads to the end of last animation. So, wow! It is show... how... eghn... great :/
2. Using `:visibe` selector to `fadeOut()` and `:not(:visible)` to `fadeIn()` ... well.. that of course did not change much, an with `stop()` it was just leaving semitransparent tooltip
3. Using `rel` attribute to define that the `fadeOut()` was already shoot and should not be shoot anymore... even worse idea, because it simply did not come back after total `fadeOut()`
4. To get some reset and thing, but I can't rest when I don't have this problem resolved - it is sooo annoying!

I wonder if anybody reads this anyway... I wouldn't.

So HOW to limit `fadeOut()`, `fadeIn()` events to one each time so it would smoothly fadeIn and fadeOut even from middle of animation when event is triggered by mousemove?

I will probably get `-1000` for this question... doooh.

Comment: Could you use css for this instead?

Comment: Agree with @troelskn, `:hover`, `opacity` and `transition` should do it.

Comment: @troelskn not sure what You mean...

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/hide/ you can try hide..it has many smooth effects

Comment: Try using [`stop(true, true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to cancel the animation.

Comment: Using css in this case has no use because as I said, the event is not trigered by top most layer... stop(true,true) works exactly te same as show() because it is called every few milliseconds, and once is enough to stop fade effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use css for this instead. You lose a bit of compatibility (Most notably older IE's), but it's simpler and will run a lot smoother.

E.g. define `opacity` in a `:hover` pseudo class, and then define a [`transition`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) property with a timing of your choice.

Edit:

> Using css in this case has no use because as I said, the event is not trigered by top most layer... stop(true,true) works exactly te same as show() because it is called every few milliseconds, and once is enough to stop fade effect.

In that case, set/unset a class on the fading-element inside your event handler. Let css do the work for you.

E.g.:

```
<style>
  #tooltip { opacity:0 ; transition:opacity 1s linear }
  #tooltip.enabled { opacity:1 }
</style>
<div class="has-tooltip">Foo</div>
<div id="tooltip">Tooltip</div>
<script>
  $(".has-tooltip")
    .on("mouseenter", function() { $("#tooltip").addClass("enabled") })
    .on("mouseleave", function() { $("#tooltip").removeClass("enabled") })
</script>
```

Comment: how can I define hover class for element that is under 10 other divs?

Comment: the same way as you do it currently. Just use css to render the animation, rather than jquery's `fadeIn/fadeOut`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to unbind events before FadeIn/fadeOut and bind again after animation is complete (in complete function).

Comment: I can't because there is alooooot going on on this mousemove that has to be done and has nothing to do with fading...

Comment: You can unbind one specific handler function with fadein/out and leave the rest of code in diffrent handler...

Comment: From manual: Example: Remove just one previously bound handler by passing it as the third argument:

var foo = function () {
  // code to handle some kind of event
};
 
// ... now foo will be called when paragraphs are clicked ...
$("body").on("click", "p", foo);
 
// ... foo will no longer be called.
$("body").off("click", "p", foo);

source: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0):

try this, call this function on mouse move

```
TIMER='';
function onmove()
{
  if(TIMER)
  clearTimeout(TIMER);
  else
  TIMER = setTimeout(function(){

  // use yor code here eg. $('whteverID').fadeIn();

  },10)

}
```